# call / Search Button by their tags using C # WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, tags

I have a screen with 25 buttons and like to interact with the buttons through the code. For example, a number is generated using the random function:

```
Random rdn = new Random ();
number = rdn.Next (0,25);
```

Let's say the result was 20. How do I call this button with the tag 20 and then change the color of his background?

```
myButton(????).Background = Brushes.Red;
```

I know I could doing one by one:

```
if (number == 1)
{
BTN_1.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
if (number == 2)
{
BTN_2.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

But it would not be right. I do not know if I was clear. Thank you

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `tag`, you mean you set Tag property of each button in XAML? or you mean the display text of the button?

Comment: `rdn.Next (0.25);` won't compile. Did you mean `rdn.Next(25);`?  Anyway, you could do a lookup via `Control.Tag` or use a `Dictionary<int,Button>`

Comment: @KingKing I mean Tag properties in XAML.

Comment: @Micky Can you give me an example? I'm starting with C # and do not have much knowledge. thanks

Comment: How do you put these buttons on the control? Are they in an ItemsControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

The first way (Using Visual Toolbox Editor):

You added 25 buttons by dragging them from the Visual Studio Toolbox

```
button1, button2 ... button25
```

If they are sorted in ORDER, you just do this:

```
int index = 1; //button1
foreach (Control c in GridOrCanvas.Children)
{
                if(c is Button && index==number){ ((Button)c).background = ...; break; }
                else index++; 
}
```

The other way (Still using visual studio toolbox):

At the beginning of your program, assign the button property "Name" to the number you want it to be (Still, thinking they are in order):

```
int ind = 1;
foreach(Control c in GridOrCanvas.Children)
{
                 if(c is Button) c.Name = "_" + ind++.ToString(); //_1
}
```

Now, you just do the same but compare strings:

```
foreach (Control c in GridOrCanvas.Children)
{
                if(c is Button && c.Name == "_" + number) { ((Button)c).background = ...; break; // "_" + 20 = "_20" }
}
```

Another way, is to add them in code by an array:

```
Button[] Buttons = new Button[25];
for(int i=0; i< Buttons.Length; i++)
{
GridOrCanvas.Children.Add(Buttons[i] = new Button() { Width = ..., Height = ..., Content = "...", ..., etc });
Canvas.SetTop(Buttons[i], top_location);
Canvas.SetLeft(Buttons[i], left_location);
}
```

You have now you array ordered by number... Buttons[0] is button1...

```
if(number > -1 && number < 26);
Buttons[number-1].Background = ...; //Faster way
```

The last and silly way, if your buttons have this:

```
Button1.Content = "Button1";
```

You just check it by this way:

```
foreach (Control c in GridOrCanvas.Children)
{
                if(c is Button) if(((Button)c).Content == "Button" + number)
                 { ((Button)c).background = ...; break; // "Button" + 20 = "Button20" }
}
```

By using tags, you just assign tags as Name:

//Assuming you already have assigned tags:
//button1.Tag = 1;

```
foreach(Control c in GridOrCanvas.Children)
{
         if(c is Button) if((int)(((Button)c).Tag) == number) { ((Button)c).background = ...; break; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I used one of your examples. It looked like this:

foreach (Control c in Grid.Children)
             {
                 if (c is Button is && c.Tag.ToString () == "00")
                 {
                     ((Button) c) .Background = Brushes.Red;
                 }
             }

It worked as I wanted!

Comment: @Ayo you're welcome! :3 There are a loooot of ways to do this ^_^

Answer (score 0):

When your create your Buttons assigne a number in Tag Property like this

```
 Button b1 = new Button();
 b1.Tag =1
```

and so on..

Your buttons are in some kind of Panel.

```
foreach (var item in myPanel.Children)
            {
                if (item is Button)
                {
                    var button = (Button)item;
                    var buttonId = (int)button.Tag;
                    if (buttonId == number)
                    {
                        button.Background = Brushes.Red
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to find any type of control based on value of any of its properties. It will return list of controls that has same value.

```
public class ChildControls
{

        static public List<PropertyInfo> getPropertiesInfo(object myobject, bool considerReadWriteAttributes, bool canRead = true, bool canWrite = true)
        {
            List<PropertyInfo> objectPropertiesInfo;
            var myType = object.GetType();

            if(considerReadWriteAttributes)
                objectPropertiesInfo = myType.GetProperties().Where(p => (p.CanRead == canRead) && (p.CanWrite == canWrite) && p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute), true).Length == 0).ToList();
            else
                objectPropertiesInfo = myType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute), true).Length == 0).ToList();

            return objectPropertiesInfo;
        }


        static public List<T> GetLogicalChildrenByProperty<T>(DependencyObject p_vParent, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            //create empty list of items of type T control
            List<T> childControlsList = new List<T>();
            List<object> childControls;

            //Get all child controls of a parent 
            childControls = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(p_vParent).Cast<object>().ToList();

            //Loop through list of child controls and if child is required Type Control and its property value equal to givenValue then add to new list and set some of its properties            
            foreach (object obj in childControls)
            {
                if (obj.GetType() == typeof(T) || obj is T)
                {
                    bool shouldAdd = false;
                    T t = (T)obj;

                    if (propertyName != null && t != null)
                    {
                        var controlPropertiesInfo = Collections.getPropertiesInfo(obj, false, true, true);
                        var controlGivenPropertyInfo = controlPropertiesInfo.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == propertyName);

                        if (controlGivenPropertyInfo != null)
                        {
                            var controlGivenPropertyValue = controlGivenPropertyInfo.GetValue(obj);

                            if (controlGivenPropertyValue == popertyValue)
                                shouldAdd = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (shouldAdd)
                        childControlsList.Add(t);
                }
            }

            return childControlsList;
        }
}
```

It is pretty generic and dynamic. You can use it in following way. In your case, it will always return list of one button as you said, each button has unique value for its Tag property.

```
List<Button> myButtons = ChildControls.GetLogicalChildrenByProperty<Button>(gdButtons, "Tag", "20");
```

Note that gdButtons is a control of type Grid (a container or parent) that contains a number of buttons (child controls) in my case.

Hope it helps you.

Cheers,